# how create select box using Array object json in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to displaying country names from json object. json data looking collection of array object, this object using ng-repeat iterating that json data and displaying into select box. i tried bellow code.

```
Json
----

$scope.countries = [
  {
    "AT": "Austria"
  },
  {
    "CI": "CÃ´te d'Ivoire"
  },
  {
    "CG": "Congo"
  },
  {
    "SV": "El Salvador"
  },
  {
    "IN": "India"
  },
  {
    "SX": "Sint Maarten (Dutch part)"
  },
  {
    "SZ": "Swaziland"
  },
  {
    "CH": "Switzerland"
  },
  {
    "AE": "United Arab Emirates"
  }
]

html
----
<select ng-model="counryNames" >
          <option ng-repeat="(key,country) in countries"  value="{{key}}">{{country[key]}}</option>
     </select>
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: select box coming empty i updated jsfiddle please check once http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/29324/

Comment: check the answer

Comment: Using [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) is just so much better than `<option ng-repeat...`. The syntax might be outlandish but `<option ng-repeat` has many weird issues that you'll run into as soon as you try to customize your select further than even the simplest use case.

Answer (score 1):

Change your ng-repeat as, you should access the key of **`countries`** not `country`

```
<option ng-repeat="(key, value) in countries" value="{{key}}">{{countries[key]}}</option>
```

**DEMO**

```js
   angular.module("myapp", [])
      .controller("MyController", function($scope) {
         $scope.countries = [{
            "AT": "Austria"
          }, {
            "CI": "CÃ´te d'Ivoire"
          }, {
            "CG": "Congo"
          }, {
            "SV": "El Salvador"
          }, {
            "IN": "India"
          }, {
            "SX": "Sint Maarten (Dutch part)"
          }, {
            "SZ": "Swaziland"
          }, {
            "CH": "Switzerland"
          }, {
            "AE": "United Arab Emirates"
          }]; 
      });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>  
</head>
<body ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
     <select>
    <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in countries" value="{{key}}">{{countries[key]}}</option>
</select>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: only i need to display country names , how can do ?

Comment: you cannot do until you modify your json

Comment: here also key sorting is there but i am asking value sorting

Comment: what do you mean ?>

Comment: pinker  first object   {name: 'Afghanistan', code: 'AF'},i chenged    {name: 'xyzcountry', code: 'AF'}, here i need name sorting(alphabetical order), how can i do?